# how to do geometry clean up in paraview?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a vtk file which has a bunch of points, I would like to delete a few points because, those distort my geometry (basic geometry clean up), is there a way I can do it in paraview? I just want to delete those points , that is it. I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Your question seems to be purely about the use of the Paraview GUI - such product-specific questions are not something this site is good for and should be asked on the [support forum](http://forum.altairhyperworks.com/index.php?/tags/forums/paraview/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have some way to distinguish between the "good" points and the "bad" points, you can use the Threshold filter to filter on point data to get rid of the undesired points. If you don't have an appropriate point data array to do this on, you can always generate one with either the Calculator filter or the Python Programmable filter.

If you want to move the "bad" points, options include the Smooth, Warp by Scalar and/or Warp by Vector filters.

Comment: Threshold won't work I have an vtk file, it just won't allow to do that. I am able to generate coords array but in no way apply filter from paraview